# Python Tkinter Tree - Image in second column and "Button" in third column?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new here, so please tell me if I make something wrong with my question (also after reading the guidelines)!

I have two questions about the Treeview in Tkinter with Python:

1. I added a picture to my second row, but I cant find a solution to bring this picture in the second column (or any other). How could I achieve that?
2. In Programs like Outlook there are elements like buttons or checkboxes (to mark as read or anything like that) Is this also possible here? To add a button or checkbox in the third column?

The code I post is just a piece of my entire code, so things like img is not declared or anything is not causing any error here!

```
tree = Treeview(obj,height = 6)
tree.grid(row=5,column=3,columnspan=2)

tree["columns"] = ("StudentID","First Name","Last Name")
tree.column("StudentID",width = 100)
tree.column("First Name",width = 100)
tree.column("Last Name", width = 100)
tree.heading("StudentID",text="StudentID")
tree.heading("First Name",text="First Name")
tree.heading("Last Name",text="Last Name")

style = ttk.Style(obj)
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40)  #'Double Row'

tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 1", values=("1A","1b","1c"), tags = ('oddrow',))
tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background='orange')
tree.insert("" , 1,    text="Line 2", values=("2A","2b","2c"),image=img)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: There's a powerful external package called [TkTreeCtrl](http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/). You might take a look [at python wrapper](http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/) to this widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answere. I try to use it but I failed to install the TkTreeCtrl Module in my Editor. I use Spyder.

Comment: A bit late, but still: Checkout [TkinterTreeCtrl](http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/)